# Iterating over a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

is there any difference between running over a vector using [], like this:

```
vector<ClassName*> my_vec(10);
int N = 10;

for (int i =0; i<N; i++){
   cout<<my_vec[i];
}
```

or, using iterators, like this:

```
for(std::vector<ClassName*>::iterator it = my_vec.begin(); it != my_vec.end(); it++) {
            cout<< (*it);
}
```

except the fact that we neet to keep an updated variable to hold vector size?

Comment: You don't have to keep a variable to hold the vector size. It tracks its own size, which you can retrieve with `my_vec.size()`.

Comment: You dont need a variable in either case, you can just call `my_vec.size()`

Comment: You do not need (and should not use!) an extra size-variable! Use `std::vector::size` instead.

Comment: This SO post is having good answers about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919406/what-is-the-difference-between-accesing-vector-elements-using-an-iterator-vs-an

Comment: Simply use for range: `for (ClassName* className : my_vec) {...}` (you may also use `auto`)

Comment: For vectors there's not much difference as both indexing and iterators are random-access. For other data structures, such as lists, you cannot use operator []

Comment: The first code is error prone.  You hardcode `10` in the declaration of the vector, then introduce an int variable that has `10`.  There are too many moving parts that can go wrong.  The second code guarantees you iterate over valid entries in the vector.