# Efficiency of vector index access vs iterator access

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

I have question to correct my understanding of efficiency of accessing elements of a vector by using index access (with operator []) or using an iterator.

My understanding is "iterator" is more efficient than "index access".
(also I think `vector::end()` is more efficient than `vector::size()`).

Now I wrote sample code measure it (under Windows 7 using Cygwin, with g++ 4.5.3)

The index access loop version (formerly labeled as random access):

```
int main()
{
  std::vector< size_t > vec ( 10000000 );
  size_t value = 0;

  for( size_t x=0; x<10; ++x )
  {
    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < vec.size(); ++idx )
    {
      value += vec[idx];
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

The iterator loop code is this:

```
    for (std::vector< size_t >::iterator iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {
        value = *iter;
    }
```

I am surprised to see that the "index access" version is much quicker. I used the `time` command to "measure". The numbers were :

> results using `g++ source.cpp`  (no optimizations)
>   index access
>
> real 800ms
>
> iterator access
>
> real 2200ms

Do these numbers make sense? (I repeated the runs multiple times) And I wondered what details I miss and why I am mistaken...

> results using g++ -O2
>   index access, time real: ~200ms
>
> iterator access, time real: ~200ms

I repeated tests on different platform (amd64 w/ g++ and power7 w xlC) and see that all the time I used optimized code the example programs have similar execution time.

**edit** changed code to add values ( `value += *iter` ) instead of just using assignment. Added details about compiler options. Added new numbers for using -O2.
**edit2* changed title correcting "iterator efficiency" to "accesses efficiency".

Comment: Make sure you're not compiling with debugging support, especially under MSVC. Also, your first version doesn't use iterators at all, and in the second version you *do* have random access iterators.

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations?

Comment: Your hunches are correct, with optimization it's the other way around, #2 is much faster.

Comment: @KerrekSB, with gcc -g is usually as fast as without except the binary becomes a little bigger. Optimization is independent of -g.

Comment: I think you are confused. Vector only has random access iterators. Indexing into a vector with `operator[]` does not involve iterators.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: I was primarily suspecting MSVC's debugging iterators. Nothing else made sense.

Comment: replace value = vec[idx]; with value += vec[idx]; in both cases to avoid the compiler beeing so smart it finds out its overwritten

Comment: added details about the compiler options (i did neither use -g nor optimizations). I rerun tests using -O2 and the numbers are now much closer. (Almost identical, but have a 5% variation of the real time)
Next step is to read now myself about the iterator vs index concepts. I will continue my experiment tomorrow using other platforms instead of my Laptop.

Comment: My Question is very close to a duplicate to this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the test harnesses, the compiler options, and how you
measured the time, it's hard to say anything.  Also, a good compiler may
be able eliminate the loop in one case or the other, since the loop has
no effect on the value returned.  Still, depending on the 
implementation, it wouldn't surprise me to see iterators significantly
faster than indexing (or vice versa).

With regards to your "understanding", there's nothing inherent about the
type of iterator and its performance.  You can write forward iterators
which are very fast, or very slow, just as you can write random access
iterators which are very fast or very slow.  Globally, the types of data
structures which will support random access iterators are likely to have
better locality than those which don't, which might work in favor of
random access iterators; but that's really not enough to be able to make
any reasonable generalizations.

Comment: I measured the execution time using the "time" command. The statement "You can write forward iterators which are very fast, or very slow," makes me challenge my simplified view. I have to revisit my thoughts. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

When I compile both programs with `-O2` (Linux, GCC 4.6.1), they run equally fast.

Then: your first program is *not* using iterators, it is using *indices*. These are different concepts.

Your second program is in fact using random access iterators, because that is what `std::vector<T>::iterator`s are. The restrictions on `std::vector` are designed in such a way that an iterator can be implemented as a simple pointer into the dynamic array that a `vector` encapsulates.

`begin` should be just as fast as `size`. The only difference between the two in a typical implementation of `std::vector` is that `end` might need to compute `begin() + size()`, though `size` might also be implemented as (roughly) `end() - begin()`. The compiler might optimize both away in the loop, though.

Comment: Actually, the implementations of `std::vector` that I've seen keep three pointers: begin, end, and one to the end of the allocated block.  Which makes `vector<>::size()` marginally slower, since it has to do `end - begin`.

Comment: I think gcc is clever enough to deduce that `end` and `size` value doesn't change so it doesn't calculate it in each iteration.. (but feel free to check the generated code)

Comment: @yi_H: good point. I actually misread the question and though the OP was comparing the performance of `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: I can confirm: using -O2 they run equally fast. I also tried -O3 and same tendency.

Answer (score 2):

With optimizations the two codes should be (near) identical. Try `-O2`.

Without optimizations and added debug information your measurements will be quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you dereference each individual item using `value = vec[idx];`, which causes an offset of `element_size * index` to be calculated each time you access an element.

Since a vector consists of elements lined up in a continuous block of memory, a vector iterator is usually just implemented as a simple pointer, so iterating through a vector (like in your second example) just involves advancing the pointer one element after each iteration.

If you enable optimizations (try `-O2` or `-O3`), however, the compiler will likely optimize your loop in the first example to something similar to the second example, making the performance nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

I have found iterators to be faster, actually.  Try refactoring your iterator loop to something like the following and you may see this as well:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
  std::vector< size_t > vec ( 1000000 );
  size_t value = 0;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  clock_t start,stop;
  int ncycle = 10000;

  start = std::clock();
  for( size_t x=0; x<ncycle; ++x ) { 
    for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < vec.size(); ++idx )
      vec[idx] += rand();
  }   
  stop = std::clock();
  cout << start << " " << stop << endl;
  cout << "INDEX: " << (double((stop - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) / ncycle << " seconds per cycle" << endl;

  start = std::clock();
  for( size_t x=0; x<ncycle; ++x ) { 
    for (std::vector< size_t >::iterator iter = vec.begin(), end = vec.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        *iter += rand();
  }   
  stop = std::clock();
  cout << "ITERATOR: " << (double((stop - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) / ncycle << " seconds per cycle" << endl;
}
```

The result is the following on my pc, showing that iterators have a slight lead:

```
INDEX: 0.012069 seconds per cycle
ITERATOR: 0.011482 seconds per cycle
```

You should note that I used an addition of rand(); this prevents the compiler from optimizing out something that it can calculate at compile time.  Compilers seem to have a much easier time doing so with intrinsic arrays than with vectors, and that can misleadingly give arrays an advantage over vectors.

I compiled the above with "icpc -fast".  slavik was right on about having to do calculations on indices vs incrementing when using iterators (ala pointers).

Comment: You do realize that "rand()" will outweight the iteration time? It is very slow. Also: You keep calling "vec.size()" inside the loop. This could also slow it down.

Comment: @Dudeson see my answer for justification for the use of rand(); the call itself is in both scenarios and will therefore weigh equally.  I'm certain that the compiler optimizes vec.size() away.

Comment: I know that you have rand() in both scenarios. But I'm not 100% sure that rand() always takes the same time to execute. Anyway. I did a physics simulation once. For that I had two nested for loops like you have. After removing the vector.size(), the performance improved noticeably!