# std::vector is indexes always faster?

Tags: c++, stl, indexing, iterator, stdvector

When using std::vector is it always faster when going trough all vector's elements via indexes than using of iterators?

I wrote simple stupid test, VS 2010, optimization is disabled

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

const int SIZE = 100000;    

int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> vInt;
    int i, temp;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
        vInt.push_back(rand());

    time_t startTime, endTime;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = vInt.begin(), itEnd = vInt.end();
startTime = clock();
for( ; it != itEnd; it++)
        temp = *it;
    endTime = clock();
    std::cout<<"Result for iterator: "<<endTime - startTime;

    i = 0;
    int size = vInt.size();
    startTime = clock();
    for(; i<size; i++)
        temp = vInt[i];
    endTime = clock();
    std::cout<<"\nResult for index: "<<endTime - startTime;    

    return 0;
}
```

***DEBUG mode:***

Without optimization results are

```
Result for iterator: 143
Result for index: 5
```

for const int SIZE = 1000;

```
Result for iterator: 0
Result for index: 0
```

for const int SIZE = 10000;

```
Result for iterator: 15
Result for index: 2
```

for const int SIZE = 1000000;

```
Result for iterator: 1377
Result for index: 53
```

**With /O2 flag**

for const int SIZE = 10000;

```
Result for iterator: 0 - 2
Result for index: 0
```

for const int SIZE = 100000;

```
Result for iterator: 12 - 15
Result for index: 0
```

for const int SIZE = 1000000;

```
Result for iterator: 133 - 142
Result for index: 0 - 3
```

So it is better always to use indexes with vector?

**UPDATE**:

***RELEASE MODE***

With **/O2 flag** all results are 0.

When optimization is disabled **/Od** indexes are faster

for const int SIZE = 100000000;

```
Result for iterator: 2182
Result for index: 472
```

for const int SIZE = 1000000;

```
Result for iterator: 22
Result for index: 5
```

for const int SIZE = 100000;

```
Result for iterator: 2 - 3
Result for index: 0 - 1
```

Comment: Your test is flawed. You re-calculate `.end()` on each iteration, and I also bet you didn't compile with optimisations turned on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, changed it. It changes numbers a little bit, but not the tendency

Comment: The comparison is not fair due to cache effect.

FYI, [a thread talking about stl:vector iterator vs. index.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added results with /O2 flag

Comment: @JinghaoShi when I did **#define _SECURE_SCL 0** nothing changed

Comment: I find this very interesting, there are a lot of cases where I don't care about using a iterators or indexers, and I often end up using  iterators for "coding style", but such performance difference might change my mind... (for these cases, I'm not saying iterators are useless)

Comment: @Julien we just have find out that this difference is only in Debug mode, in release there is no such

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wonder why these strange "benchmarks" still get upvotes. The results are usually completely bogus and of no real value whatsoever. A question which contains "debug mode" and "benchmark" should receive a default -10 votes from SO :-)

Comment: @drhirsch: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: FYI, many standard library implementations (not just VS) use special iterators in debug mode to help detect invalid use (e.g. extra bounds checking, making sure two iterators used in a comparison refer to the same container, etc.).  This extra checking can *easily* explain the difference in performance displayed here.

Comment: @drhirsch learning is making mistakes. And learning is the main idea of this site. Hopefully not everyone thinks like you, and I have learned a lot after posting this topic from answers and comments of other users. Now I see that my question is silly, but it will be impossible to understand that without posting it.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't start your post with "I wrote a simple *stupid* test...".  It doesn't help the question's credibility.

Comment: @Alecs I agree that mistakes are useful. I my native language the translations of the words "failure" and "clever" are almost identical and close relatives. But nonetheless I still do not understand why the question gets more upvotes than a downvotes. Sure the question is interesting, but that the benchmark is flawed (as in 90% of such questions) should become clear quickly IMHO. A downvote is needed in this case, if only for the reason that pain sometimes increases the chance that a learned lesson will not be forgotten :-)

Comment: Just as a simple hint: if you want a benchmark to be actually executed, you should do something with each value, e.g. replace your `temp =` with a `temp ^=`. Otherwise you are just hoping the compiler does not remove your dead code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing is that you should use whatever is idiomatic for your use case. If you are iterating I would use iterators, if you are performing random access, then indices.

Now to the actual question. Performance is hard, even measuring performance is a hard problem and it requires that you have a clear idea of what you want to measure, how you are going to measure and how different things will affect your test. Ideally you want to isolate the test so that the measurement is as precise as possible, and then run the test multiple times to verify that the results are consistent. You should never even think on measuring performance with other than fully optimized code, and ideally with a real program. If you are in debug mode and the program is slow, the best optimization is just compiling in release mode, incrementing the optimization levels, reducing debug constructs from the libraries. All of those improvements come for free.

In your test there are too many unknowns and variables to actually make anything out of it. The compiler flags and options can have a great impact so learn how to make your compiler produce the faster code. A simple implementation of an iterator for a vector is a plain pointer, so you can use this to get a base measurement:

```
int *it=&v[0], *end=it+v.size();
for (; it!=end; ++it) temp=*it;
```

This should give you a base line to which compare your iterator. Any difference in performance between the iterator and this base line is due to extra checks that you compiler/library vendor is using for debugging. Read the docs on how to disable them. Also note that your step (`it++`) requires creating one copy of `it`, in the pointer case that basically has no effect, but if the iterator maintains any state at all, the cost of `it++` will dominate the whole loop. Always prefer `++it`.

The next thing is what You want to measure and what the compiler thinks you need. You want to measure iteration, but the compiler does not know it, it only sees your code, and the optimizer will do its best to produce *equivalent* code that is as fast as possible. Taking just one of the loops, the compiler can realize that the whole iteration has no side effects other than setting temp to `v[v.size()-1]` and in the worst case (for your measurement) it can actually perform that transformation, removing the loops completely, which leads us to the next point:

The devil is in the details. My guess is that your intention is measuring the relative costs of iteration in the general case, but your program is measuring the cost of iterating over a vector of constant size. Why does this matter? Compilers perform loop unrolling to avoid the cost of the test whenever they can. If the compiler knows that your loop will always contain a multiple of X iterations, then it can test for loop completion in only one of each X steps. Optimizations are not guaranteed, and in the general case of an application, the compiler will not know the number of iterations, so you should ensure that the test does not provide the compiler with more chances to optimize than it will have in your real program. In these two cases, you want to make sure that the compiler does not have extra information that it would not have in the real case, that is, you want to hide knowledge of the test and force it to focus on the problem. I would suggest that you move the loops into functions in a different translation unit, that you pass the vector by reference, and that you ensure that it cannot avoid looping (take an integer as argument and apply a binary operator with the temporary and each element in the vector, return the result of all the operations to the caller; while processing  that function, the compiler will hopefully not be able to do anything too smart)

But above all, I must refer you back to the first paragraph, *do what's idiomatic*. Compilers are optimized for idiomatic code, and when/if performance is needed, they will do the right thing. The performance of the loop in this answer, or the two loops in the question *is* the same with unchecked iterators in an optimized build, not that the cost of the iteration itself will usually have any impact at all in the performance of your application.

Answer (score 3):

No, it depends on the compiler and optimizations flags set for compilation.

Even if you find that your compiler always produces faster code for indexes, you should not conclude that iterators are useless. The advantage of iterators is that they provide unified interface to all STL containers, which means you can write a generic template functions which, by accepting a pair of iterators, are able to work with not only vectors, but linked lists and other containers.

Also, you should use pre-increment operator instead of post-increment, this should be faster:

```
for( ; it != itEnd; ++it)
```

Comment: all my testes showed that indexes are faster the bigger size is, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at) also indexes was faster, have you examples that on some system with some compilers flags iterator was faster?

Comment: The question is "std::vector is indexes always faster?" but then after all the code and test results there is another question, slightly different: "So it is better always to use indexes with vector?"...

Comment: @piokuc isn't it almost always better to use the faster things?

Comment: @Alecs: No, definitely not. Most often it is better to write code which is more generic.

Comment: @piokuc yes, but isn't both indexes and iterators are generic?

Comment: @Alecs Iterators are more generic. There are containers which can be traversed over using iterators, but don't provide random access via subscript operator (indexes), for example linked lists.

Comment: I don't see what your testes have to do with it

Answer (score 3):

The comparison is not fair due to cache effect.

First, compile in "Release" mode if you're using VS. Or `-O2` in gcc.

After access the array elements using iterator, most of them will be cached. So when you immediately access them using index, the cache has already "warmed up". Try to do it in two separate run: one only using iterator, and another just using index. Also, try a more large data set, say 1GB. Since `clock` is not a very fine grained timer, you may want to use `rdtsc` as well.

FYI, here is [a thread talking about stl:vector iterator vs. index.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at)

Comment: when I did **#define _SECURE_SCL 0** nothing changed. Or you mean something else?

Comment: @Alecs: Do you mean this flag [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896(v=vs.80\).aspx）？ Sorry but I don't see any difference whether you enable this flag or not.
BTW, I see you're on windows. So will you compile in release mode, and also conduct the test in two **SEPARATE** program, and see the results.

Comment: I found about that flag in that [link you gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at), nothing more that have something with "cache effect" I didn't find..

Comment: Oh, yes, I completely forget about "Release" mode.. In release they both shows zeros. I should read more about "Debug" and "Release" modes differences..

Comment: @Alecs:I did a study on the `_SECURE_SCL` flag and I think you may misunderstood what I mean by "cache effect". After you access the array elements using iterators, most of them will be cached. So when you access them again after that, you get a lot more cache hit and of course the later access will be faster. I saw you biggest data size is about 4M (1M*4). So your processor may still cache most of them.

Answer (score 0):

i think your iterator times in debug mode show you the overhead of extensive iterator validation.

Without this validation overhead, but also without optimization i think iterators should be slightly slower.

You can think of iterators as a direct pointer into the internal array of the vector, so they would need only one dereference to get at the data, while to lookup by index you would need to first add, and then dereference.
But after the optimizer is done, you are unlikely to notice a difference.
What does matter though, is that if you change your code to use another container type, you may have to use iterators anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that not all containers can be used with indexes, I wanted to find out this particular with vector. I added results in release mode without optimization, you are right.