# Difference in iteration

Tags: c++11, dictionary, vector, iteration

I was trying to solve problem D from [this competition](https://codeforces.com/gym/101873/attachments/download/7413/20172018-acmicpc-german-collegiate-programming-contest-gcpc-2017-en.pdf) (it's not really important to read the task) and I noted that these two codes that make the same thing are slightly different in time of execution:

```
map < string, vector <string> > G;

// Version 1
bool dfs(string s, string t) {
    if( s == t ) return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < int(G[s].size()); i++) {
        if( dfs( G[s][i], t ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// Version 2
bool dfs(string s, string t) {
    if( s == t ) return true;

    for(auto r: G[s]) {
        if( dfs( r, t ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In particular Version 1 gets TLE in evaluation, instead Version 2 pass without any problem. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at#776629) it's strange that Version 1 is slower, and testing on my PC with the largest testcase I get same time of execution... Can you help me?

Comment: Version 1 performs a lookup `G[s]` twice per iteration. Version 2 only does it once, total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version one you have int(G[s].size())   In the for loop, which calls the size function on the variable for every iteration of the loop. Try creating a variable before the for loop that evaluates that size function once, and use it for your comparison in the loop. This Will be faster than the version 1 you currently have.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried your suggestion and it got Accepted, but it is still slower near 0.2 seconds than Version 2

Comment: Yeah, version 2 iterates over the array rather than indexing into it, which from what I recall is slightly faster in certain cases. But at least you know why the version 1 failed.